# How to use RequestContext custom attributes of armeria in log4j2.xml configuration?

Tags: log4j2, mdc, threadcontext, armeria

I'm using `log4j2 2.14.0` with `armeria 1.3.0`. According to the armeria documentation, I could see `RequestContext custom atrributes` can be exported using `com.linecorp.armeria.common.logback.RequestContextExportingAppender` in logback configuration. So, I tried to configure it in log4j2.xml but it didn't work. Is there any way to use the atrributes for setting `%X{some_value}` in log4j2.xml ? or Is it possible to use ThreadContext(like MDC) with armeria ?

Answer (score 1):

Armeria currently doesn't have the Log4J2 version of `RequestContextExportingAppender` yet. Please stay tuned by subscribing to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/line/armeria/issues/3335).